# How to join multiple words without any words, just with space in autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, in my code words are joined using comma. How do I join them without comma, just by space. I mean autocomplete shows after typing one word and giving space.

```
function split(val) {
        return val.split(/, \s*/);
    } 

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }


    function on_type() {
        $('#query').autocomplete(
                {

                    source : function(request, response) {
                        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags,
                                extractLast(request.term)));
                    },

                    focus : function() {
                        return false;
                    },
                    select : function(event, ui) {
                        var terms = split(this.value);
                        terms.pop();
                        terms.push(ui.item.value);
                        terms.push(" ");
                        this.value = terms.join(",");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a space instead of a comma? `terms.join(" ");`

Comment: Yeah but it is not working. The option will not show.

Comment: minLength property is mising for jquery autocomplete. if you set min length to a number you should get the whole string. example is set it to 10, autocomplete value may equal "123,567,9" which would join into "1235679"

Comment: Can you clarify the title to state it's for use with autocomplete please?

Answer (score 1):

Try `this.value = terms.join(" ")`

Look javascript [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) for more details

Try this as example

```js
function myFunction() {
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    console.log(fruits.join(' '))
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Join</button>
```

Here is the jQuery autocomplete plugin updated as you want. What you want to change is just to split the string with space instead of commas and join the array with space instead of commas

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];

    function split(val) {
        return val.split(" "); //Spilt array with space instead of commas
    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }

    $("#tags")
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .on("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(" "); //Join array with space instead of commas
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
    <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
```

I hope this is the solution you are lookig for.

Comment: Join does not automatically add commas `var x=[1,2,3];alert(x.join(" "))`.  It may be something to do with the jquery autocomplete that you are using, but not with join (as long as you specify *something*)

Comment: @ilovejava Please try the example that I have attached. That won't attach commas automatically. If it still happens for you, please give a fiddle for your issue.

Comment: @ilovejava which autocomplete plugin are you using? can you give a fiddler for your issue?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple. I have been using this link. In this link for autocomplete, they use comma. I just dont want to show commas in UI. @Nitheesh

Comment: @ilovejava I have updated my answer. Please look at the latest example

Comment: @Nitheesh: I mean if you check that link, in the search box there is comma shown there. My problem is I want to hide that comma. I dont want user see it.

Comment: If this was the solutions you are looking for, please approve my answer.